# Qt Necessitas windows IDE- lanunching issue

Tags: android, qt, qt-necessitas

I have installed Qt Necessitas SDK on windows 7,
I have been trying to compile and load the program to android device/emulator
I am not able to get this thing working,

Program compiles successfully and after deployment while  launching 
 I am getting the following error message

> "Starting remote process...Cannot find org.kde.necessitas.example.untitled process"

I am getting the same error for both device and emulator

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you followed the steps here ? http://qt-project.org/wiki/Setup_Necessitas_SDK_on_Windows

Comment: @opc0de i have followed the steps but some settings appear in different tabs in my QtCreator and i have not installed in the default location would that cause any problems?

Comment: Hard to say...Try this option too

Answer (score 1):

Yikes! If I read this right this is a post from 2012. The new QtCreator (5.1) works out of the box with Android for Windows--and I assume Linux (I have not tested on Ubuntu).

[http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Developing_Qt::Ports::Android](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aDeveloping_Qt%3a%3aPorts%3a%3aAndroid)

This is basically part of the IDE now.

There's a lot of possibilities for why you get that message. Did you compile for ARM5/6/7? What are you emulating? Does it have the right CPU set up? I'd take a clean install of Creator bundled so you eliminate the possibility of your local setup and run the example Android applications. This, again, works well for me on Windows which was well behind the curve on this latest release.

And yes, the documentation is really lacking right now on this front. It took me the better part of 3 hours to get it working with the emulator. One of the steps was to launch the emulator form the SDK then try connecting from my debugger.

Answer (score 0):

For Android development, I'd recommend using Qt 5.2.

Necessitas is an unofficial Android port for Qt 4. [Qt 5.1](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/07/03/qt-5-1-released/) contains an official (but incomplete) technical preview. Full official Android support will come with Qt 5.2, which will be released in December 2013.

If you want to try it out right now, the Qt 5.2 beta is available for download at http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0-beta1/. The updated documentation is at http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/android-support.html -- it is quite comprehensive now.

Here is a blog post by Digia detailing the streamlined Android deployment process: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/10/09/android-deployment-in-qt-5-2/